# How can I merge or search an object?

Tags: php, json, object

Here's my issue:

I have an object filled with arrays that look like this.

```
[376339] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1f422730-f54b-4e4d-9289-10258ce74446
        [1] => 60dc4646-06ce-44d0-abe9-ee371847f4df
    )
```

I need to search another object to find objects with the matching IDs, like below. Is there a way of doing this without a foreach? There are SEVERAL and I would like to not have to loop over the entire object every time.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1f422730-f54b-4e4d-9289-10258ce74446
    [percentage] => 32
    [destinations] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 59826
                    [destination_id] => 59826
                    [type] => Destination
                    [dequeue] => 
                    [value] => xxxxxxxxxxx
                )

        )

)
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 60dc4646-06ce-44d0-abe9-ee371847f4df
    [percentage] => 68
    [destinations] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 60046
                    [destination_id] => 60046
                    [type] => Destination
                    [dequeue] => 
                    [value] => xxxxxxxxxxxx
                )

        )

)
```

I need it to end up looking like this.

```
[376339] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1f422730-f54b-4e4d-9289-10258ce74446
                [percentage] => 32
                [destinations] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 59826
                                [destination_id] => 59826
                                [type] => Destination
                                [dequeue] => 
                                [value] => xxxxxxxxxxx
                            )
                    )
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 60dc4646-06ce-44d0-abe9-ee371847f4df
                [percentage] => 68
                [destinations] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 60046
                                [destination_id] => 60046
                                [type] => Destination
                                [dequeue] => 
                                [value] => xxxxxxxxxxxx
                            )

                    )
            )
    )
```

I'm not sure if this makes any sense, that's why I had my two inital outputs I need to have merged into one somehow. This is all coming from one huge json object and I'm just using `json_decode($jsonStuff)` to decode it.

Would this be easier if I added `true` in the decode function? If I could just search for it like I could in python, that would be neat. But as it is, I'm at a loss as to how to get the output I need.

Note: Input json CANNOT be changed, I have no affiliation with the people that created it.

Comment: You've shown two separate objects; how are you meant to search through them? Are they part of another data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First loop over your input array and create an array with the key as the id

```
$input = json_decode($json_input);
$output = array();
foreach($input as $obj){
    $output[$obj->id] = $obj;
}
```

then you can build your other array by searching the id on the array key

```
$massive_search_array = array(376339 => array
    (
        0 => 1f422730-f54b-4e4d-9289-10258ce74446,
        1 => 60dc4646-06ce-44d0-abe9-ee371847f4df
    )
);

$final_output = array();
foreach($massive_search_array as $index => $searches){
    foreach($searches as $search){
        if(isset($output[$search])){
            $final_output[$index][] = $output[$search];
        }
    }
}
```